# How to conditionally merge/join excel worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba, join, merge, conditional-statements

```
+---------+---------+  +---------+--------------+  +---------+-------------+
+ country + widgets +  + country + frammis rods +  + country + comex gears +
+---------+---------+  +---------+--------------+  +---------+-------------+
+ alpha   +       1 +  + bravo   +            8 +  + charlie +          18 +
+ bravo   +       3 +  + charlie +           16 +  + delta   +           9 +
+ charlie +       7 +  + delta   +           32 +  +---------+-------------+
+ delta   +      11 +  +---------+--------------+
+---------+---------+
```

I have several Excel worksheets like these ^^^ within the same spreadsheet.  I'm trying to create a new worksheet that contains merged data showing only those countries with data in **all** the worksheet categories.

**E.g.,**

```
+---------+---------+--------------+-------------+
+ country + widgets + frammis rods + comex gears +
+---------+---------+--------------+-------------+
+ charlie +       7 +           16 +          18 +
+ delta   +      11 +           32 +           9 +
+---------+---------+--------------+-------------+
```

I'm looking for a fairly simple, flexible way of doing this as the various worksheets are updated / new worksheets are added.  I know how to do this in MYSQL, but I'm not sure if its possible in excel.

So, what do the experts have to say?

Thx in advance. :)

Comment: if you want flexibility for new worksheet, you'll probably want to create a procedure to loop through your sheets and add any new country names to your master (merged) sheet. Once you get your merged sheets, you can use Excel's extensive formulas to grab the data you want from each sheet. If you end up adding a new sheet of "parts", you'll have to have the progam add that section as well.

Comment: +1 Scott - totally possible in VBA or VBA plus formulas, provided your tables are regular with consistent headers, but you'd have to write that code.  There's no built-in tool for this.

Comment: `I have several Excel worksheets like these ^^^ within the same spreadsheet.` I think you mean within the same `Workbook`? You can use `.Find` and `.Offset` to retrieve the data from the relevant country. One small example can be seen here in SECTION 4`http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/`

Comment: Depending on the size of the data set you may find `.find` to be quite slow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, thanks to @[MikeD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185547/miked) for an AWESOME writeup on a solution using pivot tables.  I did manage to get that working in Excel 2007.

However, I decided to use a SQL query since its MUCH faster.  (Yes, you can use SQL to merge worksheets.  Sweet!)

**1)** Data --> From Other Sources --> From Microsoft Query

**2)** Choose Data Source --> Excel Files* --> Leave "Use the Query Wizard to create/edit queries" Checked

**3)** Select Workbook

**4)** Choose the columns you want --> click next --> Click "OK" on the pop-up warning you of the need to setup a manual join

[image]

**5)** In the "Microsoft Query" window --> Table --> Joins

[image]

**6)** Click on the "Return Data" icon

[image]

**7)** Import Data --> <kbd>CTL</kbd> + Click the column headers of the duplicates (e.g., "Country2," "Country3") --> Right Click --> "Hide"

[image]

**8)** !

[image]

Comment: If no tables are visible in Step 4, click "Options" and check "System Tables"

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using a pivot table with multiple consolidation ranges. (At least in 2010) this works whether the sheets are in the same workbook or in different workbooks (see pic's)

Hint: in Excel 2010 press Alt-D, then P to access the 2003 like Pivot table wizard.

[image: Pivot Table Wizard]

no page fields

[image: 3 data sheets + Pivot consolidation]

don't forget to ask for SUM instead of COUNT (any value cell --> right click --> summarize values by)

To arrive at your final layout make an additional header line just above the Pivot table (dark blue A, B; C, ...), create an autofilter and filter for non-blank in all columns

[image]

ta-taaaaa!

Comment: Wow!  Thank you so much for the detailed writeup!  I ended up using SQL, but I learned a lot about pivot tables thanks to your post and I'm sure that will come in handy in the future. (:

Comment: @phpwns my pleasure; you will get an "outer join" as well as an "inner join" depending on how you set the filters above the pivot table ;-)

Comment: yes, it works perfectly with some minor variations in excel '07.  It just took about 4 seconds to update my data as a pivot table and less than a second using SQL (I'm merging 400+ columns).